# Can't connect to the net with RTL8111/8168B from RealTek

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers, realtek

I've successfully installed Ubuntu 12.04 and am unable to connect to a wired connection (cat5e) using my Realtek ethernet controller. It is version RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit controller (rev 06).

I've tried changing the driver to use r8168 but that has been unsuccessful as described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1992200) and [here](http://unixblogger.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/the-pain-of-an-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-ethernet-card/). The kernel drivers and module in use is r8168.

I have tried everything I know how to do, but still no luck. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This network card has a bug when using in ubuntu .

Answer (score 0):

Did you read evry errors appearing while installing r8168? Make sure so it is located in exact directory before blacklisting r8169. But, r8169 must work, but with horrible perfofrmance. For me it works great, until I change my video driver from Nouveau to NVIDIA 331.89. When I change them, r8169 almost does not work. I have tried to install r8168, but from my experience, that time my OS got broken. Just driver 8169 got deleted, 8168 did not install, and I had to pay 30eur to fix it(could not re-install OS- it blocked me).

Remember: To avoid problems like that, watch for errors and ask help to the ones, who places tutorials.